# Send a data via webhook in php

Tags: php, curl, webhooks

For one project I have to use webhook, but I don't know how using them in PHP. 
My goal is that the user submit a form, then in PHP I create a file and when the file is create I want to push the URL of this file to the client.

So it's asynchronous, the URL of the file is sent to the client (on the same page where is the form) when it has been created and client can download it. 
To do that I try something ;

```
$ch=curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"POST");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);`
```

The `$url` is the URL of the page where the form is :

`$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']."://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

And to have the data I put in my controller : 
`var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"));`

But there is not my URL file.

I assume i am all wrong on my code so I ask you for your help. 
Thanks.